# Solve Fibonacci-like linear recurrence equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

How to solve the following equation:

$f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + 1$

My best guess is that it has something to do with [Linear Recurrence Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html).  I know how to do it without the constant $1$, which is basically the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Let $b(n) = f(n) + 1$. What recurrence does $b$ have?

Comment: How stupid am I. Should have thought of it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Fischer's comment is definitely a great trick, and probably the quickest solution, but here's another way which works in a few more situations:

$f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + 1$

$f(n-1) = f(n-2) + f(n-3) + 1$

Subtracting one from the other gives:

$f(n)-f(n-1) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) - f(n-2) - f(n-3)$

$f(n) = 2f(n-1) - f(n-3)$

So now you are back in the case with no constant term. This same trick works if for example you define a recursion $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + F_n$ where $F_n$ denotes the usual Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. No offence, I still like @DanielPischer's thought :P

Answer (score 1):

No dirty tricks, plain old generating functions. Define $G(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n) z^n$, write the recurrence as:
$$
f(n + 2) = f(n + 1) + f(n) + 1
$$
Multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$; recogize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} f(n + 1) z^n &= \frac{G(z) - f(0)}{z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} f(n + 2) z^n &= \frac{G(z) - f(0) - f(1) z}{z^2} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n          &= \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align}
to get:
$$
\frac{G(z) - f(0) - f(1) z}{z^2} = \frac{G(z) - f(0)}{z} + G(z) + \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Thus:
\begin{align}
G(z) &= \frac{f(0) - (2 f(0) - f(1)) z - (f(1) - f(0) - 1) z^2}{1 - 2 z + z^3} \\
     &= \frac{(f(0) + 1) + (f(1) - f(0)) z}{1 - z - z^2} + \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align}
We know that the Fibonacci numbers have generating function:
$$
F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} F_n z^n = \frac{z}{1 - z - z^2}
$$
so that:
$$
\frac{1}{1 - z - z^2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 1} z^n
$$
Thus the values sought are:
$$
f(n) = (f(0) + 1) F_n + (f(0) - f(1)) F_{n + 1} + 1
$$